# How to add a Google sign-in option for react-native app, with AWS mobile hub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, google-signin, aws-mobilehub

Currently, I am working on a mobile application which we are building in react-native. We are using *AWS mobile hub* for the purpose.

I want to integrate the *Google sign-in* option for my mobile application. I have been searching for the actual integration flow but hard luck! I have been getting solutions for *firebase* but not any actual for AWS...

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me out to find the correct path to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the AWS-Amplify library, which provides services for federated identities (including Google sign-in)?

The general documentation is [here](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/).

The federated identity documentation is [here](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/authentication_guide#using-federated-identities-social-sign-in).

The github repository is [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify).

I hope this helps!

Comment: yes, I did try AWS-Amplify. It does not work as expected for react native. I tried `Authenticator` component along with `federated` config, but somehow, it directly takes me to the login page instead of showing a `google sign-in` button! Are there any extra steps that I need to follow?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something like this?

```
import Expo from 'expo';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Authenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  async signIn() {
    const { type, token, expires } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID', {
        permissions: ['public_profile'],
      });
    if (type === 'success') {
      // sign in with federated identity
      Auth.federatedSignIn('facebook', { token, expires_at: expires}, { name: 'USER_NAME' })
        .then(credentials => {
          console.log('get aws credentials', credentials);
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Authenticator>
        </Authenticator>
        <Button title="FBSignIn" onPress={this.signIn.bind(this)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

From the [authentication guide](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/authentication_guide).

Comment: this is another way that does include `expo` in development. I am looking for the plain way in which we can do it without any other dependency like `expo` etc